# php auto increment stops at 9 or 10000

Tags: php, wordpress, mariadb, auto-increment

The following assigns a my_id number to each item on a table in auto increment, but when it hits 10000 it starts assigning the same number 10000 to all and the auto increment stops. What in the code is causing this behavior I would like the auto increment to continue endless. Regex?

```
public static function get_new_my_id()
    {
        $query = "SELECT MAX(cast(my_id AS unsigned)) as max_id FROM #__my_items WHERE my_id REGEXP '^[0-9]+$' LIMIT 1";
        $result = my_db::select($query, 'loadResult');

        if(!$result) $my_id = 1000;
        else $my_id = $result+1;

        return $my_id;
    }
```

if I change this part: if(!$result) $my_id = **1000**; to if(!$result) $my_id = **1**; it stops at number 9 and it starts assigning 9 over again the all new items stopping the auto increment.
Same behavior

Comment: The database has an auto increment option, can you just use that?

Comment: or [sequences](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sequences/). Doing increments in application code is subject to race conditions.

Comment: Your Regex seems file. What is the data type and size used in the DB column?